# Get each values of the HTMLTableObject

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got the table row object to a variable.

```
 var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
```

But I want the individual columns of the table as String.

Doing the below just prints all the values.

```
alert(nRow.innerText);
```

I need to get the individual cell values. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.cells[index]` :

```
alert(nRow.cells[index_you_want].innerText);
```

Or also :

```
alert( $(nRow).find("td:eq(index_you_want)").text() );
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var nRow = $("table tr")[0];

alert(nRow.cells[0].innerText);
alert( $(nRow).find("td:eq(0)").text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, you can skip a step:

```js
// set "nRow" to an example row in this snippet
var nRow = $('#example tr:first');

// iterate through "td" children and get their text content 
nRow.find('td').each(function() {
  window.alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```